# There is some design. Data tables functionality working fine but on after reloading table header shrink but when I click on table its fine then

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core, datatables

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

this is my JavaScript code and My footer references and Header references. Issue is with my design on first place it showing bug design but when I click on header its showing the right design.

````
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<!--fontawesome-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/font/font/flaticon.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/StyleSheet.css">



$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#draft-data-table').DataTable({
            processing: true, // for show progress bar  
            serverSide: false, // for process server side  
            filter: true, // this is for disable filter (search box)  
            orderMulti: false, // for disable multiple column at once  
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            pageLength: 5,
            lengthMenu: [1, 3, 5, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500],
            deferRender: true,
            paging: true,
            scrollY: 200,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            scroller: true,
        });
    });```

```<script src="~/js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/popper.min.js" ></script>
<script src="~/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script src="~/libt/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hcOx.png
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From research on the issue, this is happening because you have scrollY enabled, but do not enable scrollX.

> If you are using vertical scrolling (scrollY) and not horizontal scrolling
> (scrollX), enable the horizontal scrolling option so the table has space to scroll into.

After you enable the `scrollX` option, add the following to your CSS stylesheet:

```
table.dataTable tbody th,
table.dataTable tbody td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
       var table = $('#draft-data-table').DataTable({
            processing: true, // for show progress bar  
            serverSide: false, // for process server side  
            filter: true, // this is for disable filter (search box)  
            orderMulti: false, // for disable multiple column at once  
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            pageLength: 5,
            lengthMenu: [1, 3, 5, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500],
            deferRender: true,
            paging: true,
            scrollY: 200,
            scrollX: true,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            scroller: true,
        });
    });
```

```html
<head>
<!--Styles-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<!--fontawesome-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/font/font/flaticon.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/StyleSheet.css">
<!--Scripts-->
<script src="~/js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/popper.min.js" ></script>
<script src="~/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Another work around, would be to use the `columns.adjust()` reference documented [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust()) on the DataTables website.

What this recalculate the column widths of the table. Make sure you call the `table.columns.adjust().draw();` after your table initialization

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       var table = $('#draft-data-table').DataTable({
            processing: true, // for show progress bar  
            serverSide: false, // for process server side  
            filter: true, // this is for disable filter (search box)  
            orderMulti: false, // for disable multiple column at once  
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            pageLength: 5,
            lengthMenu: [1, 3, 5, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500],
            deferRender: true,
            paging: true,
            scrollY: 200,
            scrollX: true,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            scroller: true,
        });

table.columns.adjust().draw();
    });
```

Comment: IF this answer helped please upvote :)