# Header alignment data table after added style ='100%'

Tags: datatables, yajra-datatable

I  cant align the datatable suppose to show that  header and bottom must be equal but on the image below it seems it does not equal to each other

[how to fix this datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPRNh.png)

Here is the sample code below i created to display the datatable

```
<div class="row" id='content'>
  <div class="col-md-4 pull-left">
         <div class="customCenter" >
           <a href="{{route('commendation')}}"> <img class="img-responsive rounded chooseTicket rounded mx-auto d-block" src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/paris.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" ></a>
          </div>
            <h2 class='chooseHeader'>Commendation</h2>
      </div>
      <div class=" " id='dataList'>
       
          <div class="">
             <table class="hover dataTable data-table test table-responsive" id="example" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    
                    <th>Ticket Number</th>
                    <th>Details</th>
                    <th>Created Date</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
       </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer fix your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69255919/there-is-some-design-data-tables-functionality-working-fine-but-on-after-reload

Comment: Please add your full table initialisation as well as your HTML

Comment: 1.) Do you have scrolling enabled? 2.) Did you enable the responsive option? 3.) If yes, did you correctly reference the style/script for the DataTables responsiveness option.

Comment: Yes sir BeerusDev t